# Removing google play services library

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

My app needed google maps to work. So i added google play services library in my app. Later I started using google maps directly( the app available with phone) and now I don't need google play services. So I removed that library from project by deselcting it. I did it by right clicking on my project and then selected Android option and removed the tick mark. This resulted in errors in my java files where findViewById method is used.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Maverick Whenever I'm trying to run the project in Virtual Device, it is reporting errors in project(Errors in java files).

Comment: Post Your logcat here

Comment: [2014-03-26 20:38:43 - Medi-Assist] Installing Medi-Assist.apk...
[2014-03-26 20:39:45 - Medi-Assist] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2014-03-26 20:39:45 - Medi-Assist] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-03-26 20:39:45 - Medi-Assist] Launch canceled!

Comment: I am not able to save logcat details

Comment: I think you did not removed library correctly.  You said you removed the tick sign. So did you remove the isLibrary checkbox or did you remove the library. And yeah check your logcat too

Comment: I never checked the "isLibrary" checkbox...i simply removed the tick near google library services checkbox

Comment: if it's coming that library files missing then probably you required them in your project. Try compiling after adding them